# Highlight image when link is visited

Tags: css, hyperlink, icons

How to make it in CSS that after I click on the image it wil be lighted?

My PHP:

```
<div class="social-icons highlightit">
       <ul>
      <li><a href="http://150.254.36.80/wige/kandydaci/o-wydziale/"     target="_top" rel="me"><img src="/images/wydzial2.png'" title="Wydzial"/></a></li>           
    <li><a href="http://150.254.36.80/wige/studenci/komunikaty"   target="_top" rel="me"><img src="/images/studenci.png'" title="Studenci"/></a></li>           
       </ul>
     </div>
```

My css file:

```
    .social-icons {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 22%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #F27570;
    }
    .social-icons ul {
    margin: 0;
    }
    .social-icons li {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    }
   .social-icons li img {
   display: block;
    }

   .highlightit img{
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
   -moz-opacity: 0.5;
   opacity: 0.5;
   }

   .highlightit:a.hover img{
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
   -moz-opacity: 1;
   opacity: 1;
   }
```

I tried to write

.highlightit:a.visited img{

}

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: remove extra right quote in image src tag

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your `:`s in the wring place, you need it more like...

```
.highlightit a:visited img{
```

Comment: Same for `.highlightit a:hover img{`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are in this order:

```
.highlightit a:visited img, .highlightit a:hover img {
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
   -moz-opacity: 1;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: .highlightit a:visited img {
    border:1px solid red;
}

Comment: .social-icons {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 22%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #F27570;
}
.social-icons ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.social-icons li {
  list-style: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.social-icons li img {
  display: block;
}

.highlightit img{
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
-moz-opacity: 0.7;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.highlightit a:visited img, .highlightit a:hover img {
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
   -moz-opacity: 1;
   opacity: 1;
}